# Rust beginner question, trait with generics and secure the conversion from vector to array at compile time

Tags: arrays, rust

I wonder if it is possible to implement this `Unsigned` trait that allows performing conversions from bytes arrays to this `Unsigned` type (like a constructor). The `add` function should work particularly for `u32` and `u64`. For achieving it I was thinking in doing something like this:

```rust
pub enum Error {
    BadLength,
}

trait Unsigned {
    type Array;

    const BYTES: usize;
    fn from_le_bytes(bytes: Self::Array) -> Self;
}

impl Unsigned for u32 {
    type Array = [u8; 4];
    const BYTES: usize = 4;

    fn from_le_bytes(bytes: Self::Array) -> Self {
        u32::from_le_bytes(bytes)
    }
}

fn add<W>(a: Vec<u8>, b: Vec<u8>) -> Result<W, Error>
where W: Unsigned + std::ops::Add<Output = W>
{
    if a.len() != W::BYTES || b.len() != W::BYTES {
        return Err(Error::BadLength)
    }
    const c: W = W::from_le_bytes(a[0..W::BYTES]);
    const d: W = W::from_le_bytes(b[0..W::BYTES]);
    Ok(c + d)
}

fn main() {
    const a: Vec<u8> = vec![0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04];
    const b: Vec<u8> = vec![0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04];
    if let Ok(c) = add::<u32>(a, b) {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

Currently, the compiler is telling me:

```bash
   Compiling from_le_bytes v0.1.0 (/home/guido/codes/from_le_bytes)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:28:33
   |
28 |     let c: W = W::from_le_bytes(a[0..W::BYTES]);
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found slice `[u8]`
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<W as Unsigned>::Array`
                        found slice `[u8]`
help: consider constraining the associated type `<W as Unsigned>::Array` to `[u8]`
   |
23 | where W: Unsigned<Array = [u8]> + std::ops::Add<Output = W>
   |                  ++++++++++++++

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:29:33
   |
29 |     let d: W = W::from_le_bytes(b[0..W::BYTES]);
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found slice `[u8]`
   |
   = note: expected associated type `<W as Unsigned>::Array`
                        found slice `[u8]`
help: consider constraining the associated type `<W as Unsigned>::Array` to `[u8]`
   |
23 | where W: Unsigned<Array = [u8]> + std::ops::Add<Output = W>
   |                  ++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `from_le_bytes` due to 2 previous errors
```

Is there any way to compile the code, transform those vectors into u32 and do the addition?

Comment: Are you sure you need `a` and `b` to be `const` and not `let`?

Comment: I agree with @ChayimFriedman. This is a common misconception from people coming from Javascript. `const` in Javascript is the equivalent of `let` in Rust, and `let` from Javascript is equivalent to `let mut` in Rust.

Comment: Your calculation is out of range for `b`.

Comment: Can this code compile and run? [Yes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d4cecdd1253a7fdf5a732341e45646b9). But I don't see a way of ensuring that `Array` is actually a `[u8; BYTES]`. :/

Comment: @ChayimFriedman absolutely, it is out of range for `b` I am fixing it now, it still throwing the same error.

Comment: @gagiuntoli Would you mind elaborating further what you are trying to achieve? I'm not sure if I understand the intention of the code, and I think there are a couple of things that need to be changed to achieve what I think it does.

Comment: @Finomnis I edit the description, change the function name, and what I want to achieve at the end. Please let me know if it still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
pub enum Error {
    BadLength,
}

trait Unsigned {
    type Array;
    fn from_le_bytes(bytes: Self::Array) -> Self;
}

impl Unsigned for u32 {
    type Array = [u8; 4];
    fn from_le_bytes(bytes: Self::Array) -> Self {
        u32::from_le_bytes(bytes)
    }
}

fn add<W>(a: Vec<u8>, b: Vec<u8>) -> Result<W, Error>
where
    W: Unsigned + std::ops::Add<Output = W>,
    Vec<u8>: TryInto<W::Array>,
{
    let a: W::Array = a.try_into().map_err(|_| Error::BadLength)?;
    let b: W::Array = b.try_into().map_err(|_| Error::BadLength)?;

    let c = W::from_le_bytes(a);
    let d = W::from_le_bytes(b);

    Ok(c + d)
}

fn main() {
    let a: Vec<u8> = vec![0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04];
    let b: Vec<u8> = vec![0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04];
    if let Ok(c) = add::<u32>(a, b) {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

```
134611970
```

### Explanation

I noticed that the [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) is implemented for `Vec<u8>` and `[u8; N]`:

```rust
impl<T, A, const N: usize> TryFrom<Vec<T, A>> for [T; N]
```

This means if we have the full type, including `N`, we don't need the `BYTES` constant.

Further, we can use whether or not the `try_into` worked or failed to determine if the length was correct.

So therefore, I:

- Changed the type `Array` to carry the length information `N` at compile time
- Removed the `BYTES` constant
- Replaced the length check with a success check of `try_into()`

And I replaced some erroneous `const`s with `let`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Finomnis, it has worked. I didn't need to specify that the `Unsigned` trait should derive from the `Sized` trait. Could you explain why are you doing that?

Comment: My bad. Not needed. Fixed.

Comment: I still have an issue @Finomnis; how to proceed if now I take a slice of a vector, imagine that `a` and `b` have 20 elements each and now I want to get the first 4 bytes `a[0..4].try_into().map_err(|_| Error::BadLength)?` now I have to search how to convert that slice into an array, is that possible?

Comment: @gagiuntoli How about [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec5af50d0d60d81c406e8ee372dc18a5)?

Comment: there is still an issue in the error handling of the code; for example, if one passes a vector with less than 4 bytes as an argument the `try_into()` will not execute since the code will fail when he tries to get the slice (`thread 'main' panicked at 'range end index 4 out of range for slice of length 3'`). Do you think my original way of handling the error in the length is also valid, i.e. asking for the vector length? if I leave it that way, I don't see why the `try_into` could fail then; what should I do with the `map_err` if it is never activated?

Comment: Feel free to play around with it. I'm sure you will figure out many ways to solve this problem with many advantages and disadvantages.